# Assigning two class names from functions in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am having a hard time assigning multiple functions and class names for d3 elements. I have tried :

```
.attr('class', (d) => `${d['ORDER_CATALOG_TYPE']}`, (d)`${d['ORDER_STATUS']}`)
```

(this assigns the first returned function as a class but not the second function.)

as well as

```
.classed((d) => '${d["ORDER_CATALOG_TYPE"]}', true)
```

(this assigns the function as the name of the class)

Any insight on this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add several class by separating them by a space :

```
.attr("class", "class1 class2")
```

See : https://jsfiddle.net/js84ptey/1/

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tim! That works but erases the old class names that have already been assigned. I needed some way to assign new class names without the old class names being removed.

Answer (score 1):

Was able to create a work around by using nested functions to assign the result of the function as the class name.

```
function getClassAssignment (attString) {

  return function (d) { 
    let element = select(this);
    element.classed (d[attString], true);
    return element.attr('class');
  }
}
```

This keeps the old class names and I can assign the new class names with

```
.attr('class', getClassAssignment('ORDER_CATALOG_TYPE'))
.attr('class', getClassAssignment('ORDER_STATUS'))
```